# The behavior of Helm Chart defined postStart hook on a container when the container dies

Tags: kubernetes, charts, hook, kubernetes-helm

In Helm Chart, one can define a postStart hook with parameters from the values.yaml file.

WIf the container dies and replaced, or upgraded, will postStart always be called with the same values in each start of a container?

Comment: How can I define postStart using helm `values.yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postStart and preStop are container lifecycle events so as long as your deployment configuration is not changed, those hooks will be called in each restart.